# Curious behavior of when-not and/or defmulti

Tags: clojure, symbols

Why does it happen that after I execute `defmulti` within a `when-not`, the previously unresolved symbol resolves fine, but not bound to the value?

```
user=> (resolve 'buux)
nil

user=> (when-not (resolve 'buux) (defmulti buux class))
nil

user=> (resolve 'buux)
#'user/buux

user=> (bound? #'buux)
false

user=> (defmulti buux class)
#'user/buux

user=> (bound? #'buux)
true
```

Comment: @Rainer Joswing, Clojure is a Lisp. Why remove the tag?

Comment: Clojure is a Lisp derived language. the question is so Clojure specific that it is unlikely that any, say, Emacs Lisp user could contribute to it. I would also not tag C++ specific questions with an Algol or C tag. The operators you mentioned, defmulti and when-not are also special to Clojure as is the effects of using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

defmulti will be expanded with a let-block that uses `def` to define the symbol. As a matter of fact, the expression returned by `defmulti` will not be evaluated, but it will be generated as form using let, Thus, the object becomes defined globally. This results in your test-condition (for when not) to succeed after the var has been defined, before the multi-fn was created and the root binding of the var was affected. Your defmulti block was never executed (also the when-not expression returned nil), but expanded.

Further explanation:

Here you can see how that happens:

```
(macroexpand '(defmulti buxx class))
```

Now you can see the form that the macro call will generate:

```
(clojure.pprint/write (macroexpand '(defmulti buxx class))
                      :with-dispatch clojure.pprint/code-dispatch) 
=> 
(let*
 [v__4080__auto__ (def buxx)]
 (clojure.core/when-not
  (clojure.core/and
   (.hasRoot v__4080__auto__)
   (clojure.core/instance? clojure.lang.MultiFn @v__4080__auto__))
   ...
```

This results in `(def buux)` being expanded. If you evaluate `(def buux)` in your repl you can make the same tests.

From the docstring of def:

> def yields the var itself (not its value).

This means, when being expanded, it is being replaced with a (possibly unbound) var.

So when being expanded, def always creates a var but the optional form that returns the new value (for the var) will be only evaluated when the expanded def is evaluated. Macros and special forms will be expanded before they are actually evaluated. E. g. testing with

```
(defmacro i-have-side-effects
  []
  (println "I was invoked!")
  42)
(when-not true
  (println (i-have-side-effects)))

=>
#'user/i-have-side-effects
I was invoked!
nil
```

So probably you should not define a multi-method conditionally anyway.

Comment: I don't understand this - " def always creates a binding but the optional form that returns the new value (for the var) will be only evaluated when the expanded def is invoked." - what does this mean?

Comment: What should I do if I need this exact functionality in what I am writing?

Comment: Question1: It means that whenever you use def in code that will is read, the var will be created. It will not necessarily be bound, depending on whether that part of the code will be evaluated. Question2: You should use a different test than `resolve`. Consider writing a modified version of `defmulti`. https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/c6756a8bab137128c8119add29a25b0a88509900/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1584

Comment: It seems the check is already made here - https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/c6756a8bab137128c8119add29a25b0a88509900/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1622. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the helpful responses!